# Analyzing Census Data in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to write a perl script that will parse census data (http://pastebin.com/hNzke4V8).

The script needs to parse the data, and for each county, print the county name, the population per square mile of land (population/land area), and the percentage of the county that is water (water area / (land area + water area)).

At the end, the script needs to print the county name and the value for the following criteria.

```
Highest population density
Lowest population density
Highest percentage of water
Lowest percentage of water
```

Below is an example of what the output should look like:

```
County                Population/sq mile    % Water
Adams County    307.2                         88.1%
Asotin County     111.8                        12.6%
[... etc ...]

Highest population density: Adams County, 9999 people/square mile
Lowest population density: Pierce County, 3 people/square mile
Highest percentage of water: Whitman County, 90.2% water
Lowest percentage of water: Skagit County, 3.6% water
```

This is what I have come up with so far (I'm not very familiar with perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

#initialize stuff
my %water;
my %popdensity
my @fields;
my $county;
my $lowest_pop_county=0; 
my $lowest_pop=9999999;
my $highest_pop_county=0;
my $highest_pop=0;
my $lowest_water_county=0;
my $lowest_water = 1;
my $highest_water_county = 0;
my $highest_water = 0;

#parse input
while (<>)
{
next if /County Name/;
chomp;
@fields = split /,/;
$water{$fields[0]} = $fields[3] / ($fields[2] + $fields[3]);
$popdensity{$fields[0]} = $fields[1] / $fields[2];

foreach $county (keys %water %popdensity)
{
    #print values
    print "The percent water for $county is %.2f%%\n", 100 * $water{$county};
    print "The population per square mile of land for $county is $popdensity{$county}\n";

    #determine highest and lowest values
    if ($highest_pop < $popdensity{$county})
    { 
        $highest_pop = popdensity{$county}; 
        $highest_pop_county = $county;
    } 
    if ($lowest_pop > $popdensity{$county})
    { 
        $lowest_pop = popdensity{$county}; 
        $lowest_pop_county = $county; 
    }
    if ($highest_water < $water{$county})
    { 
        $highest_water = $water{$county}; 
        $highest_water_county = $county;
    }
    if ($lowest_water > $water{$county})
    { 
        $lowest_water = $water{$county}; 
        $lowest_water_county = $county; 
    }
}

#print highest and lowest values
print "Highest population density: $highest_pop_county, $highest_pop\n"
print "Lowest population density: $lowest_pop_county, $lowest_pop\n"
print "Highest percentage of water: $highest_water_county, $highest_water\n"
print "Lowest percentage of water: $lowest_water_county, $lowest_water\n"
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the script (perl -w script.txt census.txt), I encounter the following error:

```
Operator or semicolon missing before %popdensity at script.txt line 28.
Ambiguous use of % resolved as operator % at script.txt line 28.
syntax error at script.txt line 8, near "my "
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 8.
Global symbol "$lowest_pop_county" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 10.
Global symbol "$lowest_pop" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 11.
Global symbol "$highest_pop_county" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 12.
Global symbol "$highest_pop" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 13.
Global symbol "$lowest_water_county" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 14.
Global symbol "$lowest_water" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 15.
Global symbol "$highest_water_county" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 16.
Global symbol "$highest_water" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 17.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 24.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 25.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 25.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 25.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 25.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 26.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 26.
Global symbol "@fields" requires explicit package name at script.txt line 26.
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not modulus (%)) at script.txt line 29, near     "popdensity)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Bunch of syntax errors. Missing semicolons and a missing } for the while loop. And `keys` expects only one hash. But that is no problem as those both hashes have the same keys.

This version at least compiles:

```
#!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/bin/perl


#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

#initialize stuff
my %water;
my %popdensity;
my @fields;
my $county;
my $lowest_pop_county=0; 
my $lowest_pop=9999999;
my $highest_pop_county=0;
my $highest_pop=0;
my $lowest_water_county=0;
my $lowest_water = 1;
my $highest_water_county = 0;
my $highest_water = 0;

#parse input
while (<>)
{
next if /County Name/;
chomp;
@fields = split /,/;
$water{$fields[0]} = $fields[3] / ($fields[2] + $fields[3]);

$popdensity{$fields[0]} = $fields[1] / $fields[2];

foreach $county (keys %water)
{
    #print values
    print "The percent water for $county is %.2f%%\n", 100 * $water{$county};
    print "The population per square mile of land for $county is $popdensity{$county}\n";

    #determine highest and lowest values
    if ($highest_pop < $popdensity{$county})
    { 
        $highest_pop = $popdensity{$county}; 
        $highest_pop_county = $county;
    } 
    if ($lowest_pop > $popdensity{$county})
    { 
        $lowest_pop = $popdensity{$county}; 
        $lowest_pop_county = $county; 
    }
    if ($highest_water < $water{$county})
    { 
        $highest_water = $water{$county}; 
        $highest_water_county = $county;
    }
    if ($lowest_water > $water{$county})
    { 
        $lowest_water = $water{$county}; 
        $lowest_water_county = $county; 
    }
}
} # while loop

#print highest and lowest values
print "Highest population density: $highest_pop_county, $highest_pop\n";
print "Lowest population density: $lowest_pop_county, $lowest_pop\n";
print "Highest percentage of water: $highest_water_county, $highest_water\n";
print "Lowest percentage of water: $lowest_water_county, $lowest_water\n";
```

Comment: You haven't corrected `$highest_pop = popdensity{$county};` into `$highest_pop = $popdensity{$county};`.

Comment: True, that's wierd, it does compile for me without that. With strict and warnings. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can (actually should) eliminate the `foreach` loop by just tracking the highest/lowest pop/water.  For example, if the new water% is greater than the last, replace the last with the new.  This way you'll always have the highest water%.  Do the same for the other three values.  The `foreach` is extremely inefficient, since you traverse all keys for each new county.

Your variable use is fine, but I'm inclined to use a [hash of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Declaration-of-a-HASH-OF-ARRAYS) (HoA) to track the high/low information.  Here's an HoA structure:

```
my %hash = ('high_pop' => ['King County','912.87']);
```

You get the county name by `$hash{high_pop}[0]` and the population by `$hash{high_pop}[1]`.

Given the above, consider the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
$hash{high_pop}[1]   = 0;
$hash{low_pop}[1]    = 9999999;
$hash{high_water}[1] = 0;
$hash{low_water}[1]  = 100;

print "County\tPopulation/sq mile\t% Water\n";
while (<>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    chomp;

    my @fields    = split /,/;
    my $popSqMi   = sprintf '%.2f', $fields[1] / $fields[2];
    my $percntWat = sprintf '%.2f', ( $fields[3] / ( $fields[2] + $fields[3] ) ) * 100;

    print "$fields[0]\t$popSqMi\t$percntWat\n";

    if ( $popSqMi > $hash{high_pop}[1] ) {
        $hash{high_pop}[0] = $fields[0];
        $hash{high_pop}[1] = $popSqMi;
    }

    if ( $popSqMi < $hash{low_pop}[1] ) {
        $hash{low_pop}[0] = $fields[0];
        $hash{low_pop}[1] = $popSqMi;
    }

    if ( $percntWat > $hash{high_water}[1] ) {
        $hash{high_water}[0] = $fields[0];
        $hash{high_water}[1] = $percntWat;
    }

    if ( $percntWat < $hash{low_water}[1] ) {
        $hash{low_water}[0] = $fields[0];
        $hash{low_water}[1] = $percntWat;
    }
}

print "\nHighest population density: $hash{high_pop}[0], $hash{high_pop}[1]\n";
print "Lowest population density: $hash{low_pop}[0], $hash{low_pop}[1]\n";
print "Highest percentage of water: $hash{high_water}[0], $hash{high_water}[1]\n";
print "Lowest percentage of water: $hash{low_water}[0], $hash{low_water}[1]\n";
```

Hope this helps!